# Can't select checkbox, Selenium WebDriver, Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am currently unable to select a checkbox (check it) with Selenium WebDriver in Java. I tried everything. Locating it by Xpath,  CssSelector, ID,Linktext, Partial LinkText... WebDriver fires the click... but the checkbox remains unchecked.

Now the bizar thing is, when I record it with Selenium IDE and play back, it checks the checkbox without any problem. But when I use the same code and locators in java... the checkbox does not get checked.

I tried handling it as a checkbox, I tried clicking it, I tried clicking the label. But I can not get it to work and it is starting to fustrate me.

Here is the code for the checkbox on the page I want to access it:

```
<div class="accept-terms">
                <div class="row">

                    <input id="sso-bonus-card-terms" name="cgvAccepted" class="checkbox-custom" data-msg-ssoBonusCardTerms="Veuillez accepter les conditions gÃ©nÃ©rales de SSO et Carrefour Bonus Card" type="checkbox" value="true"/><label for="sso-bonus-card-terms">J'accepte les <a href='#'>conditions g&eacute;n&eacute;rales</a> de SSO et Carrefour Bonus Card<span class='obligated'>*</span></label><input type="hidden" name="_cgvAccepted" value="on"/>
```

Here is my code to acces it now... (I allready have a central Webdriver Instance in my project, so the elements on the page are allready defined and located)

```
    @FindBy(css = "#registrationForm > div.registration-form-wrapper > div.registration-box.bonus-points-payment > div > div > div > div.col-xs-10 > div > div.card-bonus-content.card-no > div.accept-terms > div > label:nth-child(2)")
private WebElement ssoBonusCardTerms;

public SubscriptionWizardPage acceptGeneralConditions(){
    logger.info("Scroll down and accept the general conditions");
    townCityInput.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
    focus.moveToElement(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"registrationForm\"]/div[4]/div[6]/div/div"))).perform();
    focus.moveToElement(webDriver.findElement(By.id("sso-bonus-card-terms"))).perform();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    focus.moveToElement(ssoBonusCardTerms).click().perform();
    return new SubscriptionWizardPage();
}
```

Comment: When I select it by name: I get this message... "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" Although it is visible...

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your selenium version, if that doesn't fix. try this:

```
WebElement elementChkBox= driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']")
Webdriverwait wait = new Webdriverwait(driver,10)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator);
if(!elementChkBox.isSelected()) {
checkbox.click();
OR
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementChkBox);
}
```

Comment: I had this same problem and the JS code was the only one that worked. In my situation, it happens only when running the tests against a remote Selenium Grid. Very strange, but your workaround is fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Am guessing there maybe sync issue on load, object is not visible when action perform, lets put some explicit wait

public SubscriptionWizardPage acceptGeneralConditions()
{
WebElement checkbox= driver.findelement(by.xpath("//input[@id="sso-bonus-card-terms"][@name="cgvAccepted"]")
Webdriverwait wait = new Webdriverwait(driver,10)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator);
checkbox.click();
}
```

reply me the result

Comment: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable:

Comment: The attribute says it is hidden... but I can't make it work... been spending two days on it now... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
        js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"[for='sso-bonus-card-terms']\").click();");

Comment: This solution is pretty much the same as written by @Ranjith's in one of the answers. You should accept his answer as right.